# same method or variable name in a javascript class behaves differently

Tags: javascript, class, es6-class

```
class Parent{
    method(){
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    method(){
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}
var child = new Child();
console.log(child.method);
```

console return method in child class which is a expected behaviour.

```
class Parent{
    method = "sss"
}
class Child extends Parent{
    method(){
        console.log("Child")
    }
}
var child = new Child();
console.log(child.method)
```

why does the console return method variable - "sss" in Parent class ?

Comment: Parent has a property method which is 'sss'. It also has a function called 'method'. To call the function use child.method().

Comment: @Wimanicesir — JavaScript doesn't work that way. A method is a just a property where the value is a function. The value here is a string.

Comment: **In JavaScript, a class can have both methods and properties. When you create a class using the ES6 class syntax, you can define methods and properties within the class.** It's not because you approach is like a prop, you can't call it a method. I think it's way more clear to speak in these terms.

Comment: @Wimanicesir — It really isn't. "Method", in JS, is a named given to a property where the value is a function. That it is all.

Comment: Also from the mdn webdocs: *Classes are in fact "special functions"* So from now on off. Don't say class anymore but say special function...

Comment: @Wimanicesir — We're getting bogged down in terminology. Method is a useful term for a property where the value is a function. It isn't useful to pretend that methods are special in some way beyond that. They certain don't provide a way for `child.method` to simultaneously be both a string and a function at the same time. (Let's not go into the possibility of adding a `toString` method to a function and then assigning it as a property value because that isn't what the question is about).

Comment: @mohamedSikkandarAfzalM ... 1/2 ... Invoking the `Parent` implementation of `class Parent { method = "sss" }` does create a public `method` property on the instance. It's like one would have implemented `Parent` like `class Parent { constructor() { this.method = "sss"; } }`. The `Child` implementation of `class Child extends Parent{ method() { console.log("Child"); } }` on the other hand does declare a prototypal method on `Child.prototype`.

Comment: @mohamedSikkandarAfzalM ... 2/2 ... Invoking the `Child` constructor creates an instance where the parent's public `method` property (a string value) does shadow the prototypal child `method` (a function type), because the former becomes a `Child` instance's own property (via `Parent`) whereas the latter is not owned by a `Child` instance but would have been inherited (if not shadowed because of the same name) via `Child.prototype`.

Answer (score 4):

```js
class Parent {
    method = "sss";
}
```

Is essentially a shortcut for:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.method = "sss";
    }
}
```

Meaning that there are some important differences with:

```js
class Parent {
    method() {
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}
```

1. In the `method = "sss"` variant, `method` will be set as an own property of the created instance (`new Child()`).

   ```
   child.hasOwnProperty("method") //=> true
   ```

   Whereas defining a normal method `method() { console.log("Parent") }` will not be set as an own property of the instance. Instead it is set on the prototype chain.

   ```
   Parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty("method") //=> true
   ```
2. The constructor code only runs whenever you initialize an instance. Meaning that `this.method = "sss"` will always run after you've defined the `Parent` and `Child` classes (whenever you create the instance with `new`).

```js
class Parent {
    prop = "parent value";
    // aka
    // constructor() {
    //   this.prop = "parent value";
    // }
    method() {
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    prop() {
      return "child Value";
    }
    method() {
        console.log("Child");
    }
}

const child = new Child();

const log = (jsString) => console.log(jsString, '//=>', eval(jsString));
log(`child.hasOwnProperty("prop")`);
log(`child.hasOwnProperty("method")`);
log(`Parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty("prop")`);
log(`Parent.prototype.hasOwnProperty("method")`);
```

The final Child instance structure looks like this:

```js
new Child()
// returns
Child{ // Child instance depicted using object notation
  // own properties
  prop: "parent value", // set by the Parent constructor

  // prototype chain depicted using the __proto__ (deprecated) property
  __proto__: {
    // Child.prototype
    prop() { return "child Value" },
    method() { console.log("Child") },

    __proto__: {
      // Parent.prototype
      method() { console.log("Parent") },
    }
  }
}
```

For more detailed info I suggest reading through the MDN [Public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) page.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)

> Public instance fields are added to the instance either at construction time in the base class (before the constructor body runs), or just after super() returns in a subclass.

i.e. it masks the method because it is assigned around the time the constructor runs.

`child.method` is a property (with a value that is a string) on the object itself. This masks the `method` on the prototype which is a function.

---

The code below demonstrates.

You can see that in example `a` (your code) the string value for `method` is a property of `child` itself, but you can dig through the prototype chain to get the function value from the class.

In example `b` (with the public instance field removed), the method exists and can be called, but isn't on the `child` itself (because its an instance of the class so it can search the prototype chain automatically because it isn't masked).

```js
const a = () => {
  class Parent {
    method = "sss"
  }
  class Child extends Parent {
    method() {
      console.log("Child")
    }
  }
  var child = new Child();
  console.log("a: " + child.hasOwnProperty('method'));
  Object.getPrototypeOf(child).method();
};

a();

const b = () => {
  class Parent {}
  class Child extends Parent {
    method() {
      console.log("Child")
    }
  }
  var child = new Child();
  console.log("b: " + child.hasOwnProperty('method'));
  child.method();
};

b();
```

Comment: but it happens in the child class too - and by the same principle it should happend after the father field?

Comment: Methods are not public instance fields.

Comment: "A method is a just a property" - this is what you said earlier

Comment: @codingStarter — Yes, methods are just properties (with functions as their values) but the way the OP assigns their method here does not make it a public instance field.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, also i looked it up - and if you use method = function(){}, it will be an instance field, maybe add it for clarity